# Can you inherit the default properties of another HTML tag?

Tags: css

I want to make the `<output>` tag look the way `<input disabled>` does by default. Y'know, border, hazy background, slightly smaller text.

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-gap: 0.5em; grid-template-columns: [label] auto [field] 1fr;">
  <label for="a">disabled input field</label>
  <input disabled id="a" value="100">

  <label for="b">output field</label>
  <output id="b">100</output>
</div>
```

First I tried inspecting it to see what properties it had so I could copy them.

```css
input:disabled {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: -internal-light-dark(rgba(239, 239, 239, 0.3), rgba(59, 59, 59, 0.3));
    color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(84, 84, 84), rgb(170, 170, 170));
    border-color: rgba(118, 118, 118, 0.3);
}
```

But `-internal-light-dark` doesn't play nice with being pasted into my CSS file.

I know I can write up my own hazy background thing that will be sorta like that, and that's what I'll probably do. But before that, I just wanted to ask if there's any way to inherit the default properties of another tag?

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want to do. Since it involves HTML and CSS, could you upload a CodePen for me to better understand and be able to assist you?

Comment: Basically, no it can't.

Comment: Html elements have different properties, styles, uses, etc. You can't just guest the make opposite of it's element and use the way you want. But there's a way that an element will become the same *view* or *usage* of other element by creating it on your own.